# nn.CorssEntropyLoss documentation example is not correct?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

Tested [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) example of nn.CrossEntropyLoss. It doesn't seem to work.

```
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.randn(3, 5).softmax(dim=1)
output = loss(input, target)
print(output)
```

error:

```
RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to upgrade your torch version.

```
pip install torch --upgrade
```